# ServiceStack mixed authentication methods, multiple organizations and methods AD FS2, openId, facebook, google

Tags: openid, servicestack, adfs2.0, google-openid, federated-identity

Is it possible to add multiple authentication methods to servicestack? I have got five users:

```
 1. User 1 (Facebook account, Organization 1)
 2. User 2 (Google account, Organization 1)
 3. User 3 (AD FS2, Organization 2, https://company2.com/adfs/ls/)
 4. User 4 (AD FS2, Organization 3, https://company3.de/adfs/ls/) 
 5. User 5 (AD FS2, Organization 3, https://company3.de/adfs/ls/)
```

Authentication method should be selected by user Email. All users are in exactly one organization, emails are unique).

How to authenticate users with AD FS2?
How to implement multiple auth providers and methods?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar situation where a single user can login from different sources, in my case they can login from the site and from the social networks as well, all emails for all the possible authentication the login should be the same.

I recommend you to create customs authentication providers for each case, and persist whatever information you need on each login method, to follow your authentication logic.

in this case could be something like

```
 Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[]
{
                    container.Resolve<CustomFacebookProvider>(),
                    container.Resolve<CustomAuthProvider>(),
                    container.Resolve<CustomGoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider>(),
 }));
```

the container will resolve any dependencies you´ll have for any custom aperations, you´ll need to incorporate your persistance layer into each one of the authentication provider to run whatever the logic you need to do in order to validate the user login for example:

```
public class CustomAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
    {
        public new static string Name = AuthService.CredentialsProvider;
        public new static string Realm = "/auth/" + AuthService.CredentialsProvider;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository; // custom repo


        public CustomAuthProvider(IUserRepository userRepository, IResourceManager appSettings)
            : base(appSettings)
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            CallbackUrl = appSettings.GetString("oauth.{0}.CallbackUrl".Fmt(Name));
            RedirectUrl = appSettings.GetString("oauth.{0}.RedirectUrl".Fmt(Name));
            SessionExpiry = DefaultSessionExpiry;

        }


        public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session,
                                            ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth request)
        {

            string userName = request.UserName;
            string password = request.Password;

            if (!LoginMatchesSession(session, userName))
            {
                authService.RemoveSession();
                session = authService.GetSession();
            }

            if (TryAuthenticate(authService, userName, password))
            {
                authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
                if (session.UserAuthName == null)
                    session.UserAuthName = userName;
                OnAuthenticated(authService, session, null, null);
                return new AuthResponse
                {
                    UserName = userName,
                    SessionId = session.Id,
                    ReferrerUrl = RedirectUrl
                };
            }

            throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "400", "Invalid username or password");

        }

        public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
            IAuthSession session = authService.GetSession();
            User user = _userRepository.GetByUserName(userName);
            if ( _userRepository.login(username,password)) //or any other validation logic here
            {
                session.IsAuthenticated = true;
                session.UserAuthId = string.Format("{0}", user.Id);
                session.Id = authService.GetSessionId();
                session.LastModified = user.LastLoginDate;
                session.DisplayName = user.DisplayName;
                session.Email = user.Email;
                session.UserName = user.UserName;
                user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
                _userRepository.Update(user); //custom logic
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

and the same process should be followed by the other custom providers like facebook, google+, etc, at least this approach worked fine for me.